# Enter credentials at windows (UI login screen)

Tags: windows, login, python, automation

Have a situation where i have to enter windows credentials at UI logon screen for `automation`,

`I already have a python script running as service in system context on the box, listening to a remote machine`

My plan is to use my service to capture the Login screen and enter username and password, passed to this python service from remote machine.

After some investigation i found that `VNC` also uses a similar feature of sending credentials to remote machine and enter it at remote `windows` login screen

Pointers will be of great help.

Any other approach is also welcome.

Comment: This seems like a very weird requirement. Normally very weird/near impossible requirements means a underlying design choice is wrong. Can you explain the "big picture" goal of what you are trying to achieve and why you must use a python script to achieve that goal. This is a [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), you have told us `Y`, let us help you with `X`.

Comment: It seems difficult to achieve, however considering the example of VNC, where vnc client takes username and password and supplies it to VNC server on remote machine, which inturn authenticates and logs in to the machine, implies it should be possible